# How to add the search filter pipe with the virtualScroll in ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, search

I have used VirtualScroll concept to display the items in the screen. Now I want to add a search bar to search particular item.

```
 <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search Place" [(ngModel)]="searchPlace" showCancelButton = "focus" animated>
</ion-searchbar>
```

I have installed ng2-search-filter , Now where should I pipe the filter in the following code?

```
<ion-virtual-scroll
          [items]="listedLoadedPlaces"
          approxItemHeight="70px"
        >
          <ion-item
            [routerLink]="['/', 'places', 'tabs', 'discover', place.id]"
            detail
            *virtualItem="let place"
          >
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
              <ion-img [src]="place.imageUrl"></ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>{{ place.title }}</h2>
              <p>{{ place.description }}</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-virtual-scroll>
```

Kindly guide me through this please.